# How to decrease buffering timeout of Mongoose for MongoDB operations?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am encountering a timeout error in my Node.js application when performing MongoDB operations using Mongoose. The error message indicates a buffering timeout for an operation, as shown below:

```
MongooseError: Operation `settings.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (F:\VNBay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

I would like to decrease the buffering timeout to avoid such errors. However, I couldn't find direct documentation on adjusting the buffering timeout in Mongoose.

I tried: serverSelectionTimeoutMS, wtimeoutMS,  server: { socketOptions: { socketTimeoutMS: 5000 } }

Could you please provide guidance on how to decrease the buffering timeout for Mongoose operations? Specifically, I would like to reduce the timeout value from the default 10000ms (10 seconds) to a smaller duration like 3000ms.

Any assistance or suggestions on modifying the buffering timeout in Mongoose would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "_I would like to decrease the buffering timeout to avoid such errors_" - won't that have the exact opposite effect? If your operations are running out now at 10 seconds, wouldn't more operations timeout given a smaller 3 second opportunity to perform the same task? Have you looked into what specific problem is happening and tried to address that instead?

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @user20042973 i know this problem because i dont start my mongo. I did it on purpose, but i want to decrease timeout to load web faster in first time without database